# Windows 10 battery stuck at 97% (never 100%)

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery

I think this happens after a FORCED update (I lost the battle against Microsoft in stopping updates).

I tried 2 recommended methods out of 3 at https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-laptop-battery-not-charging-to-100-windows-10.html and both don't work. Battery report shows batt at always 96% or 97% not 100%. I plug-in all the time!

I'm using ASUS ZenBook.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a Windows issue. Charging is controlled by laptop's and battery's circuitry working together. Windows is only displaying the status that hardware reports.

If it's a major issue for you, you should consider replacing the battery.

Comment: But this happened after a Windows update.

Comment: @vocotipex It was a coincidence. Windows updates don't affect battery at all. In theory you could receive a battery firmware update via Windows Update, but I think only MacBooks have upgradeable battery firmware, and even if your hardware supports it, that wouldn't cause a fault, but rather reveal it.